# Composer no puedo instalar repositorio privado

Tags: composer

Este es el error que me sale y no sé que significa

> Root composer.json requires mirepo/util ^2.3, found mirepo/util[dev-master] but it does not match the constraint.

```js
{
    "name": "xxxx/intranet",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Intranet de xxxxx S.A.",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "homepage": "https://intranet.xxxx.com",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "xxx\\Util\\": "vendor/xxx/util/src/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "ssh://git@xxxx.xxxx.com:43202/home/git/util"
        }
    ],
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.3",
        "ext-calendar": "*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "mirepo/util": "dev-master",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
        "consolidation/robo": "^2.0",
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.10.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.0.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "kevinpapst/adminlte-bundle": "^3.1.2",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "^0.5",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.3",
        "mbence/opentbs-bundle": "^1.9",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.8",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "sentry/sentry-symfony": "^3.4",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.4",
        "symfony/console": "^4.4",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.4",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.6",
        "symfony/form": "^4.4",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "^4.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.4",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.4",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.4",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12",
        "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "^3.0",
        "ext-simplexml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "bitexpert/captainhook-validateauthor": "^0.2",
        "captainhook/plugin-composer": "^5.1",
        "escapestudios/symfony2-coding-standard": "^3.11",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "3.0.x-dev",
        "moxio/captainhook-eslint": "0.1.*",
        "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan-deprecation-rules": "^0.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan-doctrine": "^0.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan-phpunit": "^0.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan-strict-rules": "^0.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan-symfony": "^0.12",
        "rector/rector-prefixed": "^0.7",
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
        "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^5.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.4",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "thecodingmachine/phpstan-strict-rules": "^0.12"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "cs-fix": [
            "php-cs-fixer fix src --rules=@Symfony"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "xxxx\\Util\\Config\\HooksComposer::preUpdate"
        ],
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "xxxx\\Util\\Config\\HooksComposer::preInstall"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.3"
        }
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "captainhook": {
            "config": "vendor/xxxx/util/src/Config/hooks/hooks.json",
            "disable-plugin": false
        },
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        },
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfesony-assets-install": "relative"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "zzzz",
            "email": "zzz@zzz.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        },
        {
            "name": "zzzz",
            "email": "zz@zz.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. fijate que version solicitas de ese paquete en tu composer.json. entiendo que tu paquete privado esta en la version 'dev-master' y lo buscas como '2.3'
2. En el mismo archivo debes ver que estabilidad minima aceptas de los paquetes en     `"minimum-stability": "dev",`  puede ser "stable" u otras opciones, ver doc de composer

Por el error me inclino que viene por esos temas (en especial el (2))

EDIT

Intenta agregar la siguiente linea al composer.json de tu proyect

```
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
```

Debajo de la linea de

```
    "prefer-stable": true,
```

Comment: No entiendo lo de `dev-master` en teoría mi repositiorio se va actualizando mediante git aplicandole unos tags de versiones. Como hago para que apunte a la rama master y a los tags que tengo creados?

Comment: copiate el composer.json para verlo bien

Comment: El composer.json de la librería propia o el composer.json del proyecto?

Comment: mil disculpas por no aclarar, el composer.json de tu proyecto

Comment: ya lo he puesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Me sigue dando el error: `Root composer.json requires xxx/util 2.3.*, found xxx/util[dev-master] but it does not match the constraint.` habiendo puesto el minimum-stability y el prefer stable. Lo queue necesito es que pueda instalar versiones según los tags...

Answer (score 0):

Tu has hecho unos versiones de tu `package xxx/util`. Lo que te parece fallando es en el `branch dev-master` de tu componente, que necesitas decir para que version el `HEAD` de repositorio esta referiendo. En otras palabras, que tengas unas lineas asi:

```
{
   "extra": {
      "branch-alias": {
         "dev-master": "2.3.x-dev"
      }
   }
}
```

Los lineas tienes que poner en `Composer.json` de proyecto `xxx/util`. Este es solo un ejemplo, si tengas alla una version que muestra que el version `HEAD` esta mayor de 2.3, te ficas bien. Si no, tienes que añadir /cambiar una linea asi o corregir tu `require` si este no esta en linea con que ya tengas alli en dev-master.

Puedes observar algun proyecto publico que encontres cual esta usando el metodo de `Composer` en su proyecto, como lo estan poniendo el `alias` en master y cuando publican lo quitan de version que tenga el tag.

Mas documentacion en https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md